# mysql query join not joining

Tags: mysql, select, join

I want to find the users with the most experiences (most frequent contributors).

```
SELECT X.userid, count(X.id) as jobs, SUM(X.stars) as stars 
FROM experiences AS X   
RIGHT JOIN users AS U ON U.userid = X.userid
```

Experiences Table:

```
| id | userid | stars | ...
  1    1        3
  2    1        4
```

User Table:

```
| userid | username | password | photo     | ...
    1      goofy      12345678   goofy.png
    2      donald     12345678   dduck.png
    3      pluto      12345678   pluto.png
```

The problem is, the results are coming back but the join is not joining. What I'm getting is:

Results:

```
userid | jobs | stars |
 1       2       7
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
userid | jobs | stars | username | password | photo     | ...
  1       2       7     goofy      12345678   goofy.png
```

Comment: You must use GROUP BY X.userid and SELECT all the columns you want to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a join won't automatically affect your select list. If you want the joined columns, you'll have to explicitly select them:

```
SELECT     X.userid, count(X.id) as jobs, SUM(X.stars) as stars, U.*
           -- Here ----------------------------------------------^
FROM       experiences AS X   
RIGHT JOIN users AS U ON U.userid = X.userid
```

Comment: All I can say is Doh! followed by a headslap.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial `SELECT` statement handles that. The data is there, you just need to "select" it.

Essentially just:

```
SELECT X.userid, count(X.id) as jobs, SUM(X.stars) as stars, U.*
```

Where `U.*` will include the userid again, or scope it out to `username, password, photo, ...`